# How to wrap a list around a block/image?

Tags: css, list, internet-explorer-9, css-float

I'm trying to wrap a list around a block and IE doesn't make my life easier.

The block is floating on the left, so I expect the list to be on the right. While it works in all browsers, it looks pretty ugly in IE, because IE puts the text on the right and the bullets on the left of the image.

Look at the example: http://jsfiddle.net/xA9n8/

How to fix this?

UPD: I tested it in IE9.

Comment: In which version of IE is this failing? It looks fine to me in IE8.

Comment: For the last jsfiddle question I answered, the source of the bug was jsfiddle itself.  Have you tried this in a standalone HTML file with nothing else in the file?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I tried this in a standalone file and it works just like in JSFiddle

Answer (score 7):

For the googlez:

```
#somebox ul li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Giving the list items the property `float:left;` [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/xA9n8/11/). You may want to insert a `<div style="clear: left;" />` afterwards to prevent further elements from floating.

Comment: The list is below the image now, not on the right side of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ul{float:left;}`.I think it seems to work.

Comment: The list is below the image now, not on the right side of it.